# PostgreSql crashed with error: 'server process (PID XXXX) was terminated by exception 0xC0000142'

Tags: database, postgresql, debugging, profiling

I have Postgresql 9.2 running on a 4G memory, Atom N2800 CPU **Windows POS READY embedded system**(like the XP) machine, basically it running fine for years in production environment, but crashed(service stopped) frequently in recent performance(**not stress**) testing.

I don't think the testing put too much stress, by enabled the `log_min_duration_statement = 0`, the simplified overall statistics for what  the testing have done listed below:

say 20 minutes is a measure unit, so during one unit:

5000 times of **UPDATE** with each query contains 20KB size of data(contains a `Text` field).

35000 times of **SELECT** with each query returned 20KB size of data(to get that `Text` field).

the logs didn't see any abnormal until the crash and leave this:

```
2015-07-29 16:41:53.500 SGT,,,5512,,55b87f74.1588,2,,2015-07-29 15:23:32 SGT,,0,LOG,00000,"server process (PID 4416) was terminated by exception 0xC0000142",,"See C include file ""ntstatus.h"" for a description of the hexadecimal value.",,,,,,,""
2015-07-29 16:41:53.500 SGT,,,5512,,55b87f74.1588,3,,2015-07-29 15:23:32 SGT,,0,LOG,00000,"terminating any other active server processes",,,,,,,,,""
2015-07-29 16:41:53.500 SGT,"eps","transactiondatabase",6960,"127.0.0.1:9162",55b891cf.1b30,9,"idle",2015-07-29 16:41:51 SGT,146/0,0,WARNING,57P00,"terminating connection because of crash of another server process","The postmaster has commanded this server process to roll back the current transaction and exit, because another server process exited abnormally and possibly corrupted shared memory.","In a moment you should be able to reconnect to the database and repeat your command.",,,,,,,""
2015-07-29 16:41:53.515 SGT,"eps","transactiondatabase",5828,"127.0.0.1:9150",55b891c2.16c4,155,"idle",2015-07-29 16:41:38 SGT,145/0,0,WARNING,57P00,"terminating connection because of crash of another server process","The postmaster has commanded this server process to roll back the current transaction and exit, because another server process exited abnormally and possibly corrupted shared memory.","In a moment you should be able to reconnect to the database and repeat your command.",,,,,,,""
2015-07-29 16:41:53.515 SGT,"eps","transactiondatabase",6448,"127.0.0.1:9148",55b891c2.1930,5,"idle",2015-07-29 16:41:38 SGT,93/0,0,WARNING,57P00,"terminating connection because of crash of another server process","The postmaster has commanded this server process to roll back the current transaction and exit, because another server process exited abnormally and possibly corrupted shared memory.","In a moment you should be able to reconnect to the database and repeat your command.",,,,,,,""
....
....
2015-07-29 16:41:54.500 SGT,,,8004,,55b87f76.1f44,2,,2015-07-29 15:23:34 SGT,1/0,0,WARNING,57P00,"terminating connection because of crash of another server process","The postmaster has commanded this server process to roll back the current transaction and exit, because another server process exited abnormally and possibly corrupted shared memory.","In a moment you should be able to reconnect to the database and repeat your command.",,,,,,,""
2015-07-29 16:41:54.515 SGT,,,5512,,55b87f74.1588,4,,2015-07-29 15:23:32 SGT,,0,LOG,00000,"all server processes terminated; reinitializing",,,,,,,,,""
2015-07-29 16:42:04.515 SGT,,,5512,,55b87f74.1588,5,,2015-07-29 15:23:32 SGT,,0,FATAL,XX000,"pre-existing shared memory block is still in use",,"Check if there are any old server processes still running, and terminate them.",,,,,,,""
2015-07-29 16:51:02.078 SGT,,,5828,,55b893f6.16c4,1,,2015-07-29 16:51:02 SGT,,0,LOG,00000,"database system was interrupted; last known up at 2015-07-29 16:40:36 SGT",,,,,,,,,""
2015-07-29 16:51:02.093 SGT,,,5828,,55b893f6.16c4,2,,2015-07-29 16:51:02 SGT,,0,LOG,00000,"database system was not properly shut down; automatic recovery in progress",,,,,,,,,""
2015-07-29 16:51:02.109 SGT,,,5828,,55b893f6.16c4,3,,2015-07-29 16:51:02 SGT,,0,LOG,00000,"redo starts at 0/12C79578",,,,,,,,,""
2015-07-29 16:51:02.421 SGT,,,5828,,55b893f6.16c4,4,,2015-07-29 16:51:02 SGT,,0,LOG,00000,"unexpected pageaddr 0/1046A000 in log file 0, segment 19, offset 4628480",,,,,,,,,""
2015-07-29 16:51:02.421 SGT,,,5828,,55b893f6.16c4,5,,2015-07-29 16:51:02 SGT,,0,LOG,00000,"redo done at 0/13469FC8",,,,,,,,,""
```

one thing I could point is the database configuration of `shared_buffers`, now the settings is `256MB`, it just there for no reason, does it help to increase this value?

Other major setting: `max_connections=200`, `temp_buffers = 16MB`,`work_mem = 8MB`

Anyone could help to check how the crash happened, or how to minimize the scope?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[MSDN says](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/library/cc704588.aspx):

> - `0xC0000142`
> - `STATUS_DLL_INIT_FAILED`
> - {DLL Initialization Failed} Initialization of the dynamic link library %hs failed. The process is terminating abnormally.

so it was a DLL loading issue and/or issue starting a new process. If I had to guess I'd say you might have hit limits on the number of open files, number of running processes, etc on your XP Embedded system. You might want to lower `max_connections`.

Comment: Oh! I thought the error code was belong to PostgreSql.   based on your suggestion, I looked the performance monitor data which captured along with this exception, I noticed the system handles was keep rising from 3K to 10K in 3 hours until the service stopped, but when I look into each process's handles, they're all normal, do you have any suggestion?

Comment: Use Process Explorer and/or Process Monitor from Microsoft's sysinternals to get more detailed info and to try to identify what's leaking handles. Assuming that it's not just that you have growing numbers of processes, so the total handle count reaches the limit even though the number of handles held by each process is unchanged.

Comment: I can lower down the `max_connections` from current `200` and do another round of testings to see any improve.      But, we've already used postgresql odbc drivers with connection pooling enabled, so from my understanding and imagine, by lower down the `max_connections`, we would see connect db time out in client side, and the root cause for now situation is the massive connection attempting from client, correct?

Comment: @Shawn Hard to tell from the info available. Could be. I don't know much about XP embedded. Could also be a handle leak in a long running process somewhere,